# RxTx Serial Com in Java, platform independence

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I have written a java application for serial communication however it relies on **http://rxtx.qbang.org/**. The only other option I can see is  **javax.comm** which im told is out of date or not recommend ...

In the case of RXTX I ended up putting the dll's into various windows system folders as I did also did on Linux so that the JVM could see it.

It has  been very long time since I have used javax.comm but I seem to remember doing something similar.

I would really like to make my application OS independent. I like to send out my java application (JAR) file and be it  Windows (x86/64) or Linux system without previous modification it will justwork.

To that end I need to include all the necessary files within my jar.

What is the best way to achieve this ?
Is there a better Serial Communication option ?

Thanks,

Ps. Just found for Ubuntu you can install RxTx with apt-get

> sudo apt-get install librxtx-java

Answer (score 1):

Try Purejavacomm, which works using JNA without native DLLs: http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying rxtx too and worked well with my application. 
rxtx is the implementation of the specification under javax.comm

javax.comm is still in the specification but the problem comes from the fact that com ports are really low level in the OS. That's why you need rxtx and DLL / SO files.

I went through the same wishes but couldn't find the real perfect solution, What I ended up doing is to provide DLLs for Windows (my first use case) and decided to wait and see if there's a need for other OS.

But the best "advice" I can give you is : 
Do not try to program too low level. I first tried it and it worked but wasn't a great architecture. And then... I discoverd Mina => http://mina.apache.org/
It uses rxtx too but it changes the way you handle the communication by providing a whole framework. 
It's really great, you should give it a try.